# BSOD due to DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f) with virtual NIC driver

Tags: ndis

I am working on a NDIS 6 miniport virtual NIC driver which does not handle IRP_MJ_POWER or IRP_MN_SET_POWER. The driver does not register in DispatchPower function for IRP_MJ_POWER. It sets this as NULL. The driver does power management using OID_PNP_CAPABILITIES and OID_PNP_SET_POWER.

Recently I observed a crash on Windows 7 machine with code DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f). After doing some analysis, I observed that the crash happened because the driver did not process the Power IRP (IRP_MJ_POWER) for more than 10 minutes. This is the first time I observed this problem.

I am also curious to know more about delivery of IRP_MJ_POWER/IRP_MN_SET_POWER to drivers.  Is it mandatory for NDIS drivers to handle these IRPs. I have seen multiple miniport drivers that do not have dispatch function registered for IRP_MJ_POWER. If it is not mandatory and driver does not need to register dispatch function for IRP_MJ_POWER, under what conditions, such a problem can happen.

Answer (score 2):

NDIS miniports do not (and can not) handle IRPs directly.  NDIS handles them on behalf of the miniport.  In general, when you see the system exhibiting some WDM behavior (like a bugcheck that talks about IRPs) you need to mentally translate that into the equivalent NDIS concepts and callbacks.  Unfortunately this is not always obvious at first -- it takes a few years of working with NDIS to get the hang of this.

In the particular case of 9F -- that's a *very* common bugcheck for a network adapter.  About 70% of the time, it's caused because the miniport driver leaked a NET_BUFFER_LIST and didn't complete the NBL back to NDIS.  This is a common code bug, because there are otherwise no symptoms of leaking an NBL, and it's all too overlook a small leak.

About 20% of the time, a 9F in networking is caused by some other thing getting stuck, like a stuck OID or a deadlock in MiniportPause.  The remaining few percent of networking 9Fs are caused by bugs in filter drivers (who also tend to leak NBLs) and the occasional OS bug.

When debugging a 9F in a network driver, you should focus (1) identifying what thing specifically isn't getting completed (NBL, OID, function call, etc), and then (2) figure out *why* it's not getting completed.  Sometimes you get lucky, and the kernel debugger command `!stacks 2 ndis!` has all the stacks in a neat little deadlock for you to unravel.  Other times you need to add some diagnostics/counters to narrow down what happened to the NBLs.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This really helped. In my case the driver didn't complete the NBLs.